# Two icons are showing for same app on the device while installing

Tags: php, ios, testflight, ad-hoc-distribution

My app is a `'clickconf app'`, and I used the AdHoc distribution in order to allow my client to install the app on their device for testing. I am hosting my app on a TestFlight server and then installing it on the device from MobileSafari.

The problem is that when the app is almost installed, a new icon is displayed saying `"Installing"`.

I don't know whether this is an issue from iOS side or PHP side because from PHP side it is allowing the app to install on the device.

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: Its not an issue on your side. The installing icon on device with the app icon suggests that the app is currently being installed. What happens after that? does the app gets installed?

Comment: yes, app is getting installed successfully.But the same other icon is showing with installing label on icon.......

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot?

Comment: i have same problem like that link screen shot ....so u can come to know by looking that link...

Comment: I don't think it is actually installing somethingm it looks like there are two applications installed in the device. It just happens that the icon of one of them is such that it shows the text installing in it. Can you tap and open the app that says Installing?

Comment: yeah, when i click on the other icon with installing text it is not showing anything ....means nothing is happening and the magic thing is that when i long press and try to delete ,it can't be delete also because there is no option for deleting that icon........

Comment: strange. Does this only happens when you install the app from Testflight?

Comment: Test the same procedure on other devices and see if it also happens there. If it doesn't then may be its an iOS issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know its been long time but i got the answer for my question. Its issue ob mismatch bundle-identifier in plist and IPA.

So make sure bundle identifier should be same.